# Bash - Date not recognising UK format (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: bash, date, format

I have a text file with the following dates in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`:

```
14/09/1992
15/04/1983
15/09/1961
02/06/1979
14/12/1971
08/02/2001
19/06/1999
14/09/1969
31/08/2002
30/07/1980
25/04/1973
03/01/1992
```

I want to convert this into the `YYYY/mm/dd` format in a script. I was planning to use the date command to do so:

```
date -f tempDate +%Y/%m/%d
```

but the thing is, it does not recognize the English-style dates and shows the following error as i believe it is reading it as `mm/dd/yyyy` when i don't want it to:

```
date: invalid date `14/09/1992'
```

is there another way of doing this? or is there a way i can change the order of the date format?

also, I need this script to work on a server that I am not a sysadmin for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is as described why not just reverse the columns with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{print $3,$2,$1}' file
1992/09/14
1983/04/15
1961/09/15
1979/06/02
1971/12/14
2001/02/08
1999/06/19
1969/09/14
2002/08/31
1980/07/30
1973/04/25
1992/01/03
```

**Edit:**

Just as easy in `awk` with multiple field separator:

```
$ awk -F[/,] '{print $1","$2","$5"/"$4"/"$3}' <<< "name,number,14/09/1992"
name,number,1992/09/14
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way i can do this in a csv file? (so change the date around within) `name,number,14/09/1992` to `name,number,1992/09/14`. Not a master of awk... yet.

Comment: If your file is CSV, then I suggest that Perl may be better than `awk` for the task.  It can be done in `awk` (at least, GNU `awk`).  It's not particularly pretty.  (The same could be said of Perl, I suppose — it's not particularly pretty.  But, especially if you decide to use the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) extension module, it is straight-forward where in `awk` it is fiddly.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's no biggie with `awk` *~Sam_Web* see edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a quick awk script to change to the year/month/day order:

```
 awk -F '/' '{print $3"/"$2"/"$1}' < file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X at least, the `-f` option to date is documented as:

> `-f`      Use input_fmt as the format string to parse the new_date provided rather than using the default
>                `[[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]` format.  Parsing is done using `strptime(3)`.

Therefore, you should be using:

```
date -f '%d/%m/%Y' +'%Y-%m-%d' ...
```

However, the residual issue is converting multiple values; you'd need multiple invocations of `date` for that, so you'd like to try something like:

```
# Bogus code
while read date                                   # Bogus code
do date -f '%d/%m/%Y' $date +'%Y-%m-%d'           # Bogus code
done < tempDate                                   # Bogus code
# Bogus code
```

This, however, attempts to set the system clock (not very successfully unless you're `root` at the time, and you should not be `root` when experimenting).  So, there isn't an obvious way to get the `date` command to do what you want.

Therefore, the answers using `awk`, `sed`, `perl`, `python` and regular expressions to map the dates are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The international standard date format, ISO 8601, is `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `YYYY/MM/DD`. I suggest using that unless you have a very good reason not to.

The US and UK date formats are ambiguous for dates before the 13th of each month, so it's not surprising that `date` wouldn't recognize it. There could be a way to tell it that a given string is in UK format, but I don't know what it is.

You can use `sed`, or any other tool that does regular expression substitution, to change the format:

```
$ echo 14/09/1992 | sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\/\([0-9][0-9]\)\/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)/\3-\2-\1/'
1992-09-14
```

Perl can do this a bit less verbosely:

```
$ echo 14/09/1992 | perl -pe 's/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d\d\d)/$3-$2-$1/'
1992-09-14
```

or:

```
$ echo 14/09/1992 | perl -pe 's/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/$3-$2-$1/'
1992-09-14
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows you can also change your regional settings to change the date format on your computer as a whole and in particular your .csv-file:

Win7:

1./ Go to Start button
2./ Choose Control panel
3./ Clock, language and region.
4./ Change the date, time and number format.